# Vertical Align Two Blocks Middle inside main block

Tags: html, css

I have this html Structure:

```
<div class="main-block">
  <div class="img-main"><img width="45" height="43" src="#" itemprop="image"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <p> First Block </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-block">
  <div class="img-main"><img width="45" height="43" src="#" itemprop="image"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <p> Second Block </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-block">
  <div class="img-main"><img width="45" height="43" src="#" itemprop="image"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <p> Third Block </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-block">
  <div class="img-main"><img width="45" height="43" src="#" itemprop="image"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <p> Lopreum Ipsum Text Two Rows</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Main block has next styles:

```
.main-block {
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 135px;
  position: relative;
}
```

How can i vertically center two blocks, one below other? 
I can't use method with `flex` because it will break my inline style.
Also, looks like i can't use `position: absolute` since i don't know `img` height and width.

Any help?

Comment: can you provide your html code?

Comment: "I can't use method with flex because it will break my inline style." -  Use `inline-flex` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacking them vertically, wrapping them into a div and using relative position will do the tricks.

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
```

they set the distance from the top of the wrapper to the outer box to be 50% of the outer box's height.

```
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

While this transformation will translate the wrapper up by 50% of the wrapper's height.
The combination of these two leads to the vertical position of the wrapper.

```css
.main-block {
  height: 400px;
  background: silver;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
p {
  white-space: break-word;;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
p:first-child{
  background: yellow;
}
p:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block">
  <div class='inner'>
    <p>
      12 31 23 as df sd zv      
    </p><p> TE XT sdaf  asdf asdf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the CSS:

```
Postion: absolute;
Left: 0px;
Top: 0px;
Transform: translate(0vw, -4.5vh);}
```

Explaination:
This makes the object stuck in the top left corner. And then you move it around with `Transform:`
The formatting in `Transform:` can be `px,% and vw/vh`.

Doing this to all of your objects will give you full control of their positions, but make sure that everything is scalable (I recommend using the `vh/vw` formatting) :-)

EDIT:
Also having the exact same class on each of the `<div>` will make it hard to position objects, and `Transform:` :-)

Comment: FYI the `Transform: translate(0vw, -4.5vh)` is copy pasted from my own css, do not use those values :-)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that you get used to Flexbox, check the complete guide [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)